# SQL query using Like and Between in the same statement

Tags: php, sql

so here is my problem I need to select records in between year 2000-2008 but the columns I need to search for is in type varchar example:

```
IntRecordID     VARCHARYear
    1            1990-2000
    2            2001-2005
    3            2005-2006
    4            2007-2008
    5            2009-2020
```

select all record id that has VARCHARYear between 2000 and 2008

```
IntRecordID
    2
    3
    4
```

what is the sql query that I need to achieve this?

Comment: what hv you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your `VARCHARYear` field always be inn `YYYY-YYYY` format.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_name
WHERE   LEFT(VARCHARYear,4)     >   2000
    AND RIGHT(VARCHARYear,4)    <=  2008
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql will be like this...

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE LEFT(column_name, 4) >= value1 AND RIGHT(column_name, 4) <= value2
```

I suggest that you better add another 2 columns for you year, and separate your years let say "year_from" and "year_to" and make this columns `year` as datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query:
Here I try to segregate year by using [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) and [CHARINDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp) function since you want to use BETWEEN clause on *VARCHARYear* column.
eg: `SUBSTRING(VARCHARYear,1,(CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARYear)-1))`
Then I try to collect same *IntRecordID* data/row of duration of year(such as: 1990-200) of same column by **UNION**.
eg:
`SELECT IntRecordID
        ,SUBSTRING(VARCHARYear,1,(CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARYear)-1)) AS VARCHARYear
  FROM TABLE1
  UNION
  SELECT IntRecordID
         ,SUBSTRING(VARCHARYear,(CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARYear)+1),len(VARCHARYear)) AS VARCHARYear
    FROM TABLE1`
Finally I use **DISTINCT** to fetch duplicate *IntRecordID* data one time.
Hope it'll be help full for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IntRecordID
FROM
(
 SELECT IntRecordID
        ,SUBSTRING(VARCHARYear,1,(CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARYear)-1)) AS VARCHARYear
  FROM TABLE1
  UNION
  SELECT IntRecordID
         ,SUBSTRING(VARCHARYear,(CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARYear)+1),len(VARCHARYear)) AS VARCHARYear
    FROM TABLE1
  )T
   WHERE CONVERT(INT,T.VARCHARYear) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2008
```